# Select all columns from a table that matches an id in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table structure like this

Customer

```
CustomerID|CustomerName|CustomerPhone|CustomerAddress
123       |Jason       |219632369    |4 pine street
485       |David       |219632369    |4 pine street
586       |Ramsay      |219632369    |4 pine street
779       |Jacob       |219632369    |4 pine street
```

Order

```
OrderID|CustomerID|ItemCode|ItemDesc
425    |123       |456     |Intel i7
427    |123       |456     |Intel i7
428    |485       |456     |Intel i7
429    |123       |456     |Intel i7
430    |485       |456     |Intel i7
431    |123       |456     |Intel i7
```

Expected output

```
CustomerID|CustomerName|CustomerPhone|CustomerAddress
123       |Jason       |219632369    |4 pine street
485       |David       |219632369    |4 pine street
```

I want to select all the columns from the customer table who have entries in orders table using the customerid

This is what I tried

```
select * 
from customer 
where customerid = (select customerid 
                      from order);
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Exists` to search such customers since it avoids problems in case some order does not have a `customerid` specified. If some `customerid` is `null` in `order` the `IN` predicate is evaluated to unknown and it means that the no customer is returned.

```
select *
from customer c
where exists (
  select 1
  from "order" o
  where o.customerid = c.customerid 
)
```

Try to avoid using keywords for table names (`order`), it may cause unexpected troubles when writing SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

you can accomplish this by using an inner join as well, just an additional solution:

```
select distinct cust.* from Customer cust inner join Order o on cust.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
```

Comment: That would return each customer as often as they placed an order not only once.

Comment: Thanks @sticky bit i have updated the query to add distinct

Answer (score 0):

Use the `IN` operator:

```
select * 
from customer
where customerid in (select customerid from order)
```

Comment: you can also look at 'exists' in sql

Comment: I think `EXISTS` may be even faster.

Comment: @TheImpaler `in (subquery)` and `exists (subquery)` tend to be transformed to the same semi-join with the same plan, so I would be surprised if there was any difference.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thanks, never really thought about it. I would try to compare execution plans.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson You are right. I just compared both execution plans and they are identical. You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You have can create aliases for the tables, this is equal: select all from customer where customerid exists on orders

Select A.*
from customer a, order b
where a.customerid = b.customerid